# AWS S3 Java API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, java

I am using AWS S3 service for managing files which will be invoked from Android App. AWS provide java API which is around 18MB in size for all AWS Services(EC2, S3, etc.). I need API only for AWS S3, so that I can reduce App Size.

Where can I get AWS S3 Java API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vinod

As per AWS documentation, you don't require to import full sdk in your Android app to use S3 Client. You can do following:

To use S3 from your mobile app, first set up the AWS Mobile SDK for Android:

Download the Android SDK and include it in your project, as described at Set Up the SDK for Android. You'll need to drag aws-android-sdk-2.#.#-core.jar and aws-android-sdk-2.#.#-s3.jar into the libs directory of your project.

Include the following imports in your project:

```
 import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
 import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.*;
 import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
```

Find the full tutorial here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use [minio-java](https://github.com/minio/minio-java) client library, its open source & compatible with AWS S3 API & is of small size. You can see all the example code with Put, Get, Post & other operations https://github.com/minio/minio-java/tree/master/examples

Hope it helps.
Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://www.minio.io)